# Trouble computing $\int_0^\pi e^{ix} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, substitution

> I am trying to compute the integral of $\int_0^\pi e^{ix} dx$ but get the wrong answer. My calculations are $$
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \int_0^\pi e^{ix} dx &=& (1/i) \int_0^\pi e^{ix} \cdot i \cdot dx = (1/i) \Bigl[ e^{ix} \Bigr]_0^{\pi} \\
> &=& (1/i) \Bigl[ e^{i\cdot \pi} - e^{i\cdot 0} \Bigr] = (1/i) \Bigl[ -1 - 1 \Bigr] \\
> &=& -2 / i
> \end{eqnarray}
> $$

But WolframAlpha says the answer is $2i$. What am I missing?

Comment: Try multiplying top and bottom of the final answer by $i$, what do we get?

Comment: $1/i$ is $-i$ so you win.

Comment: Heh. thanks guys. $i$ is tricky that way...

Comment: For all numbers $n$, $$-\frac{n}{i} = (-1)\bigg(\frac{n}{i}\bigg) = i^2\bigg(\frac{n}{i}\bigg) = \frac{n}{i}$$ In your case, $n = 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have taken all the right steps so far $$ 
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\pi e^{ix} dx &=& (1/i) \int_0^\pi e^{ix} \cdot i \cdot dx \\
&=& (1/i) \Bigl[ e^{ix} \Bigr]_0^{\pi} \\
&=& (1/i) \Bigl[ e^{i\cdot \pi} - e^{i\cdot 0} \Bigr] \\
&=& (1/i) \Bigl[ -1 - 1 \Bigr] \\
&=& -2 / i = 2i
\end{eqnarray}$$ Note that $i$ is the pure imaginary number satisfying $i^2 =-1$.

Thus $1/i = -i$ which implies $-2/i =2i$

Comment: $i^2\neq i$. It is that $i^{4m + 1} = i$ for positive integers $m\geqslant 0$. Instead, $i^2 = -1$, but I believe you knew that anyway and perhaps made a typo.

Comment: A typo..........................

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Yes $i^2=-1$ indeed.

Answer (score 1):

your answer is correct just see that $-i =\frac{1}{i}$. Whereas it could be simpler to write

$$e^{ix} = \cos x+i\sin x$$

Then $$\int_0^\pi e^{ix} dx = \int_0^\pi \cos x dx+i\int_0^\pi \sin x dx \\ =\left[\sin x\right]_0^\pi+i\left[-\cos x\right]_0^\pi=2i$$